# Want to set up a system of sending email to users on my magento store who have forgot a password

Tags: email, magento, forgot-password

I have set up a magento store of my own for my business of grocery products.

I have almost configured each and everything.

I have a mail server and can have as many email addresses as I require.

I have a theme set up for the store.
While a user tries to log in and has forgot a password, there is a link to click saying "Forgot Password".
On clicking it, it displays "An email has been sent to your account with new password details."

I know this will not send an email as I have to configure entire system.
I do not want to send a new password by email. Instead I want to send a link. On clicking this link, the user can go the it and have an option of password reset.

Please help me with this. It will be much much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code snippets you tried yet to clarify the question.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Actually, I tried all other things on my store and was trying to find a way to figure the email for forgot password system. I would have sent the code snippets. But honestly, I do not know how to configure them with the mail server from magento back end in first place.

Comment: Magento 1.6.x.x and beyond don't send a password. It sends a link to the user's email address so they can change their password. It already does what you ask.

Comment: @FiascoLabs  Thank you so much for the reply. http://www.vedvasavada.com/ash_projects/antistaticesd_new
Here is my Magento installation with the Porto theme. Please see to it. The functionality does not seem to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found out something after a test. As you mentioned, the password reset email is received. But not on any gmail account. If there are users with emails of their own server other than gmail, they can receive emails and then reset passwords. Please tell me if you have any thoughts on how can users registered with gmail accounts, receive such password reset emails.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. You should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I already have put it there sir. But received no reply:   http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65627/password-recovery-through-sending-a-link?noredirect=1#comment87770_65627

Answer (score 0):

Magento's standard "Forgot Password" functionality works exactly as you've described - it sends a link to the user to reset his or her password - it doesn't just send a new password.

Magento uses `Zend_Mail` to send emails. By default, `Zend_Mail` will use PHP's `mail()` function (via `Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail`), which will usually send emails via `sendmail` or similar, depending on the PHP configuration.

If you have your own mail server that you'd prefer to use, you can configure Magento to use SMTP. This does require some code, but, luckily, there are some good extensions out there that already do this, like [aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension](https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension).

Comment: Hello @Agop. Many Thanks. vedvasavada.com/ash_projects/antistaticesd_new Here is my Magento installation with the Porto theme. Please see to it. The functionality does not seem to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found out something after a test. As you mentioned, the password reset email is received. But not on any gmail account. If there are users with emails of their own server other than gmail, they can receive emails and then reset passwords. Please tell me if you have any thoughts on how can users registered with gmail accounts, receive such password reset emails.

Comment: Troubleshooting email delivery problems is really outside of the scope of this question. You'll need to check your mail server's SMTP logs and figure out why the Gmail delivery failed. Google has a troubleshooting steps here: https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2920052?hl=en